# Cannot connect to VM (GCE) using SSH

Tags: google-compute-engine

I cannot connect to my compute server VM using SSH.
It says "retrying 2/3..  3/3"

It seems as if the server is actually running and functioning.
I have Apache Tomcat with some apps installed and MySql server.
I can connect to the apache tomcat manager page and I don't see any problem there.
I can connect to my MySQL database using client tool such as MySQL WorkBench.
I can insert new rows to tables and delete some. It doesn't look like a ran out of free disk space.
Anyways I tried to delete some data from tables and shrink it but apparently free space is not the issue.

Here is a Serial Port log I got. Please, what can cause this?
I use to be able to connect under same conditions (same client machine, firewall, etc.) so the issue is from the server side.

```
[34987645.468284] Free swap  = 0kB
[34987645.471547] Total swap = 0kB
[34987645.474838] 157083 pages RAM
[34987645.478109] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
[34987645.482323] 4886 pages reserved
[34987645.485853] 0 pages hwpoisoned
[34987645.489270] [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes swapents oom_score_adj name
[34987645.497494] [  311]     0   311     6350     1726      14        0             0 dhclient
[34987645.506101] [  358]     0   358     6869       60      18        0             0 cron
[34987645.514339] [  369]     0   369    64668      459      29        0             0 rsyslogd
[34987645.522954] [  373]     0   373     1064       38       8        0             0 acpid
[34987645.531266] [  406]     0   406     3604       38      12        0             0 agetty
[34987645.539669] [  407]     0   407     3604       38      12        0             0 agetty
[34987645.548081] [  408]     0   408     3604       40      12        0             0 agetty
[34987645.556571] [  409]     0   409     3604       40      12        0             0 agetty
[34987645.564986] [  410]     0   410     3604       39      12        0             0 agetty
[34987645.573414] [  411]     0   411     3604       39      12        0             0 agetty
[34987645.583546] [  412]     0   412     3559       40      10        0             0 agetty
[34987645.591939] [ 7263]     0  7263    13796      168      29        0         -1000 sshd
[34987645.600464] [11774]   107 11774    10565      124      25        0          -900 dbus-daemon
[34987645.610085] [20473]   104 20473     7292      146      19        0             0 ntpd
[34987645.618585] [27741]     0 27741    13169     2273      30        0             0 google_accounts
[34987645.627869] [27744]     0 27744    13211     2284      29        0             0 google_clock_sk
[34987645.637039] [27747]     0 27747    13211     2244      30        0             0 google_ip_forwa
[34987645.646401] [14807]     0 14807    10176      101      22        0         -1000 systemd-udevd
[34987645.655412] [30481]     0 30481     1085       43       6        0             0 mysqld_safe
[34987645.664327] [30815]   109 30815   221020    12045      81        0             0 mysqld
[34987645.672765] [15984]     0 15984     7218       64      19        0             0 systemd-journal
[34987645.681934] [19949]   108 19949   547956    45017     173        0             0 java
[34987645.690161] [23671]     0 23671    10560       86      26        0             0 cron
[34987645.698380] [23672]     0 23672     1085       22       7        0             0 sh
[34987645.706415] [23673]     0 23673     1057       20       8        0             0 run-parts
[34987645.715058] [23674]     0 23674     1085       37       6        0             0 apt
[34987645.723279] [23793]     0 23793    28771     5257      62        0             0 unattended-upgr
[34987645.732642] [23803]     0 23803    28579     5281      57        0             0 unattended-upgr
[34987645.741809] [24237]     0 24237     4583      418      14        0             0 dpkg
[34987645.750026] [24239]     0 24239     1085       23       7        0             0 google-cloud-sd
[34987645.759214] [24241]     0 24241    62608    51157     126        0             0 python2
[34987645.767782] [24263]     0 24263    12231      155      28        0             0 sshd
[34987645.775989] [24265]     0 24265    10553       79      26        0             0 cron
[34987645.784795] [24266]     0 24266    12203      131      27        0             0 sshd
[34987645.793015] [24267]     0 24267    12203      132      25        0             0 sshd
[34987645.801461] [24268]     0 24268    12203       85      25        0             0 sshd
[34987645.809715] [24270]     0 24270    12203       85      25        0             0 sshd
[34987645.817941] [24271]     0 24271    12203       82      25        0             0 sshd
[34987645.826202] [24272]     0 24272    12203       68      24        0             0 sshd
[34987645.834413] [24273]     0 24273    12203       66      26        0             0 sshd
[34987645.842619] [24274]     0 24274    12203       65      25        0             0 sshd
[34987645.850850] [24275]     0 24275     4527       26      11        0             0 sshd
[34987645.859165] Out of memory: Kill process 24241 (python2) score 326 or sacrifice child
[34987645.867298] Killed process 24241 (python2) total-vm:250432kB, anon-rss:204628kB, file-rss:0kB
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.059900] sshd invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x201da, order=0, oom_score_adj=-1000
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.067997] sshd cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.072637] CPU: 0 PID: 7263 Comm: sshd Not tainted 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 Debian 3.16.7-ckt25-2+deb8u3
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.081960] Hardware name: Google Google/Google, BIOS Google 01/01/2011
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.088955]  0000000000000000 ffffffff8150e08f ffff880025daa9a0 0000000000000000
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.097277]  ffffffff8150bc8b 0000000000000000 ffffffff810d51ff 0000000000000000
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.105594]  ffffffff815129ae 0000000000000200 ffffffff81067933 ffffffff810c2914
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.113999] Call Trace:
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.116817]  [<ffffffff8150e08f>] ? dump_stack+0x5d/0x78
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.122507]  [<ffffffff8150bc8b>] ? dump_header+0x76/0x1e8
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.128393]  [<ffffffff810d51ff>] ? smp_call_function_single+0x5f/0xa0
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.135306]  [<ffffffff815129ae>] ? mutex_lock+0xe/0x2a
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.140921]  [<ffffffff81067933>] ? put_online_cpus+0x23/0x80
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.147045]  [<ffffffff810c2914>] ? rcu_oom_notify+0xc4/0xe0
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.153083]  [<ffffffff81151bfc>] ? do_try_to_free_pages+0x4ac/0x520
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.159842]  [<ffffffff8114090d>] ? oom_kill_process+0x21d/0x370
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.166311]  [<ffffffff811404cd>] ? find_lock_task_mm+0x3d/0x90
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.172614]  [<ffffffff81141073>] ? out_of_memory+0x473/0x4b0
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.178769]  [<ffffffff81146e6d>] ? __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x9cd/0xb30
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.185690]  [<ffffffff8118600d>] ? alloc_pages_current+0x9d/0x150
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.192273]  [<ffffffff8113f670>] ? filemap_fault+0x1a0/0x420
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.198395]  [<ffffffff8116546a>] ? __do_fault+0x3a/0xa0
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.204172]  [<ffffffff8116802e>] ? do_read_fault.isra.54+0x4e/0x300
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.210908]  [<ffffffff8116985c>] ? handle_mm_fault+0x63c/0x11c0
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.217288]  [<ffffffff81161009>] ? vmacache_find+0x29/0xd0
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.223513]  [<ffffffff810572a7>] ? __do_page_fault+0x177/0x4f0
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.229813]  [<ffffffff8109d237>] ? put_prev_entity+0x57/0x350
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.236015]  [<ffffffff8109c0a6>] ? set_next_entity+0x56/0x70
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.242146]  [<ffffffff810a2e71>] ? pick_next_task_fair+0x6e1/0x820
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.248870]  [<ffffffff810115dc>] ? __switch_to+0x15c/0x5a0
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.254812]  [<ffffffff81516228>] ? page_fault+0x28/0x30
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.260832] Mem-Info:
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.263586] Node 0 DMA per-cpu:
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.267258] CPU    0: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.272519] Node 0 DMA32 per-cpu:
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.276345] CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:  76
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.281531] active_anon:126526 inactive_anon:3096 isolated_anon:0
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.281531]  active_file:813 inactive_file:900 isolated_file:0
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.281531]  unevictable:0 dirty:0 writeback:0 unstable:0
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.281531]  free:8071 slab_reclaimable:2225 slab_unreclaimable:4588
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.281531]  mapped:1028 shmem:3130 pagetables:1213 bounce:0
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.281531]  free_cma:0
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.314947] Node 0 DMA free:3088kB min:788kB low:984kB high:1180kB active_anon:11608kB inactive_anon:108kB active_file:12kB inactive_file:152kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:15992kB managed:15908kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:0kB shmem:112kB slab_reclaimable:88kB slab_unreclaimable:480kB kernel_stack:16kB pagetables:52kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:522 all_unreclaimable? yes
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.356698] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 576 576 576
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.361878] Node 0 DMA32 free:29196kB min:29300kB low:36624kB high:43948kB active_anon:494496kB inactive_anon:12276kB active_file:3240kB inactive_file:3448kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:612340kB managed:592796kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:4112kB shmem:12408kB slab_reclaimable:8812kB slab_unreclaimable:17872kB kernel_stack:2320kB pagetables:4800kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:11577 all_unreclaimable? yes
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.406481] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.411143] Node 0 DMA: 22*4kB (UE) 19*8kB (UEM) 12*16kB (UEM) 7*32kB (UEM) 4*64kB (UEM) 1*128kB (U) 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 1*2048kB (R) 0*4096kB = 3088kB
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.428083] Node 0 DMA32: 383*4kB (E) 310*8kB (UEM) 450*16kB (UEM) 200*32kB (UEM) 109*64kB (EM) 4*128kB (E) 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 1*4096kB (R) = 29196kB
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.445684] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.454775] 4860 total pagecache pages
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.458908] 0 pages in swap cache
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.462650] Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.468284] Free swap  = 0kB
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.471547] Total swap = 0kB
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.474838] 157083 pages RAM
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.478109] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.482323] 4886 pages reserved
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.485853] 0 pages hwpoisoned
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.489270] [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes swapents oom_score_adj name
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.497494] [  311]     0   311     6350     1726      14        0             0 dhclient
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.506101] [  358]     0   358     6869       60      18        0             0 cron
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.514339] [  369]     0   369    64668      459      29        0             0 rsyslogd
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.522954] [  373]     0   373     1064       38       8        0             0 acpid
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.531266] [  406]     0   406     3604       38      12        0             0 agetty
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.539669] [  407]     0   407     3604       38      12        0             0 agetty
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.548081] [  408]     0   408     3604       40      12        0             0 agetty
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.556571] [  409]     0   409     3604       40      12        0             0 agetty
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.564986] [  410]     0   410     3604       39      12        0             0 agetty
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.573414] [  411]     0   411     3604       39      12        0             0 agetty
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.583546] [  412]     0   412     3559       40      10        0             0 agetty
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.591939] [ 7263]     0  7263    13796      168      29        0         -1000 sshd
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.600464] [11774]   107 11774    10565      124      25        0          -900 dbus-daemon
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.610085] [20473]   104 20473     7292      146      19        0             0 ntpd
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.618585] [27741]     0 27741    13169     2273      30        0             0 google_accounts
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.627869] [27744]     0 27744    13211     2284      29        0             0 google_clock_sk
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.637039] [27747]     0 27747    13211     2244      30        0             0 google_ip_forwa
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.646401] [14807]     0 14807    10176      101      22        0         -1000 systemd-udevd
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.655412] [30481]     0 30481     1085       43       6        0             0 mysqld_safe
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.664327] [30815]   109 30815   221020    12045      81        0             0 mysqld
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.672765] [15984]     0 15984     7218       64      19        0             0 systemd-journal
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.681934] [19949]   108 19949   547956    45017     173        0             0 java
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.690161] [23671]     0 23671    10560       86      26        0             0 cron
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.698380] [23672]     0 23672     1085       22       7        0             0 sh
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.706415] [23673]     0 23673     1057       20       8        0             0 run-parts
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.715058] [23674]     0 23674     1085       37       6        0             0 apt
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.723279] [23793]     0 23793    28771     5257      62        0             0 unattended-upgr
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.732642] [23803]     0 23803    28579     5281      57        0             0 unattended-upgr
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.741809] [24237]     0 24237     4583      418      14        0             0 dpkg
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.750026] [24239]     0 24239     1085       23       7        0             0 google-cloud-sd
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.759214] [24241]     0 24241    62608    51157     126        0             0 python2
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.767782] [24263]     0 24263    12231      155      28        0             0 sshd
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.775989] [24265]     0 24265    10553       79      26        0             0 cron
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.784795] [24266]     0 24266    12203      131      27        0             0 sshd
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.793015] [24267]     0 24267    12203      132      25        0             0 sshd
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.801461] [24268]     0 24268    12203       85      25        0             0 sshd
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.809715] [24270]     0 24270    12203       85      25        0             0 sshd
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.817941] [24271]     0 24271    12203       82      25        0             0 sshd
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.826202] [24272]     0 24272    12203       68      24        0             0 sshd
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.834413] [24273]     0 24273    12203       66      26        0             0 sshd
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.842619] [24274]     0 24274    12203       65      25        0             0 sshd
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.850850] [24275]     0 24275     4527       26      11        0             0 sshd
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.859165] Out of memory: Kill process 24241 (python2) score 326 or sacrifice child
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.867298] Killed process 24241 (python2) total-vm:250432kB, anon-rss:204628kB, file-rss:0kB
Sep  2 16:21:27 instance-1 dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 169.254.169.254 port 67
Sep  2 16:21:27 instance-1 dhclient: DHCPACK from 169.254.169.254
Sep  2 16:21:27 instance-1 dhclient: bound to 10.132.0.2 -- renewal in 40860 seconds.
Sep  2 21:14:06 instance-1 systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
Sep  2 21:14:06 instance-1 systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Sep  3 03:42:27 instance-1 dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 169.254.169.254 port 67
Sep  3 03:42:27 instance-1 dhclient: DHCPACK from 169.254.169.254
Sep  3 03:42:27 instance-1 dhclient: bound to 10.132.0.2 -- renewal in 34630 seconds.
Sep  3 13:19:37 instance-1 dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 169.254.169.254 port 67
Sep  3 13:19:37 instance-1 dhclient: DHCPACK from 169.254.169.254
Sep  3 13:19:38 instance-1 dhclient: bound to 10.132.0.2 -- renewal in 33626 seconds.
Sep  3 21:14:22 instance-1 systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
Sep  3 21:14:22 instance-1 systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Sep  3 22:40:04 instance-1 dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 169.254.169.254 port 67
Sep  3 22:40:04 instance-1 dhclient: DHCPACK from 169.254.169.254
Sep  3 22:40:04 instance-1 dhclient: bound to 10.132.0.2 -- renewal in 38182 seconds.
Sep  4 09:16:26 instance-1 dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 169.254.169.254 port 67
Sep  4 09:16:26 instance-1 dhclient: DHCPACK from 169.254.169.254
Sep  4 09:16:26 instance-1 dhclient: bound to 10.132.0.2 -- renewal in 35099 seconds.
Sep  4 19:01:25 instance-1 dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 169.254.169.254 port 67
Sep  4 19:01:25 instance-1 dhclient: DHCPACK from 169.254.169.254
Sep  4 19:01:25 instance-1 dhclient: bound to 10.132.0.2 -- renewal in 40004 seconds.
Sep  4 21:14:26 instance-1 systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
Sep  4 21:14:26 instance-1 systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
```

Comment: Which method are you using to connect? Are you able to login to other VM instances? And did you verify following login methods: [gcloud shell](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#sshingcloud) and [using third party](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#thirdpartytools) tool (eg: putty) to connect to VM instance?

Answer (score 1):

This question is 3 years old, but I posted my answer for anybody who is facing similar issues. At first, please have a look at the [serial port messages](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/viewing-serial-port-output#console):

```
[34987645.859165] Out of memory: Kill process 24241 (python2) score 326 or sacrifice child
[34987645.867298] Killed process 24241 (python2) total-vm:250432kB, anon-rss:204628kB, file-rss:0kB
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.059900] sshd invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x201da, order=0, oom_score_adj=-1000
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.067997] sshd cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
...
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.859165] Out of memory: Kill process 24241 (python2) score 326 or sacrifice child
Sep  2 08:16:18 instance-1 kernel: [34987645.867298] Killed process 24241 (python2) total-vm:250432kB, anon-rss:204628kB, file-rss:0kB
```

if you see messages like these: `Out of memory` , `sshd invoked oom-killer` and so on, that means that your server is running out of free memory.

**To solve this issue** you should shutdown your VM instance, change its [machine type](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types) to another one with more memory or use [custom](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#custom_machine_types), then save changes and and start your VM. In addition, you can use [Cloud Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring) to be aware about resource usage of your VM.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how you are connecting to this VM instance via SSH, I would suggest reviewing the following documentation on troubleshooting SSH issues:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh

Some common causes of SSH connection issues are as follows:

- [OS Login is enabled on the instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#enable_oslogin). You cannot use both metadata-based SSH keys and OS Login to connect to an instance. If OS Login is enabled, then connecting with metadata-based SSH keys is disabled because OS Login does not store SSH keys in authorized keys files.
- [OS Login is not enabled](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages/tree/master/packages/python-google-compute-engine#accounts). When OS Login is not enabled, Google manages the authorized keys file for new user accounts based on SSH keys in metadata. A Compute Engine instance no longer accepts SSH connections using the SSH keys configured as part of your user account.
- The accounts daemon stores a file in the guest to preserve state for the user accounts managed by Google.
- The authorized keys file for a Google-managed user account is deleted when all SSH keys for the user account are removed from metadata.
- User accounts that are not managed by Google are not modified by the accounts daemon.
- The instance has a full disk. Check your disk space and clean it up as needed.
- The `sshd` daemon is not configured properly. Review the user guide for your operating system to ensure that your [ssh_d](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config) file is set up correctly.